# Reinstall all packages removed on a certain day?

Tags: apt, package-management

While trying to remove a list of packages starting with 'texlive' I accidentally removed more than expected.

Instead of doing:

```
sudo apt-get remove '^texlive.*'
```

I did:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'texlive.*'
```

First of all: can someone confirm me that the packages listed were actually removed? I thought that I would be prompted for confirmation anyway but it didn't happen so I'm in doubt. I checked 3/4 of them from the list and they appear not to be installed but I can't be sure they were installed in the first place.
Anyhow, I now have a huge list of packages which may have been removed. I immediately saved the list which the command showed in the stdoutput and managed to parse the package list inside a file. Is there a quick way to reinstall all the packages removed on a certain day or do I need to manually reinstall them from the list just to be sure?

This is an example of the output:

```
Note, selecting 'libtext-dhcpleases-perl' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'jtex-base' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'libghc-texmath-prof-0.11.2.2-aa9c7' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'texlive-plain-generic' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'kbibtex-data' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'latex-cjk-japanese' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'python3-texttable' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'lintex' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'latex-coffee-stains' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'context-nonfree' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'sword-text-gerlut1545' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'libdjvulibre-text' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'mathtex' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'texstudio-l10n' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'libboost-context1.67-dev' for regex 'tex.*'
Note, selecting 'latex-cjk-chinese' for regex 'tex.*'
```

Reading online I took a look also inside `/var/log/apt/history.log` and this is the output for today:

```
Start-Date: 2021-01-16  20:09:45
Commandline: apt remove texlive
Requested-By: bernardo (1000)
Remove: texlive:amd64 (2019.20200218-1)
End-Date: 2021-01-16  20:09:46

Start-Date: 2021-01-16  20:10:08
Commandline: apt install texlive
Requested-By: bernardo (1000)
Install: texlive:amd64 (2019.20200218-1)
End-Date: 2021-01-16  20:10:08

Start-Date: 2021-01-16  20:57:35
Commandline: apt remove texlive
Requested-By: bernardo (1000)
Remove: texlive:amd64 (2019.20200218-1)
End-Date: 2021-01-16  20:57:35

Start-Date: 2021-01-16  21:02:13
Commandline: apt-get remove tex-common tex-gyre texinfo
Requested-By: bernardo (1000)
Remove: texlive-plain-generic:amd64 (2019.202000218-1), tex-common:amd64 (6.13), texlive-latex-base:amd64 (2019.20200218-1), lmodern:amd64 (2.004.5-6), texinfo:amd64 (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5), texlive-base:amd64 (2019.20200218-1), texlive-pictures:amd64 (2019.20200218-1), texlive-fonts-recommended:amd64 (2019.20200218-1), texlive-latex-extra:amd64 (2019.202000218-1), preview-latex-style:amd64 (11.91-2ubuntu2), texlive-lang-italian:amd64 (2019.20200218-1), tipa:amd64 (2:1.3-20), tex-gyre:amd64 (20180621-3), texlive-binaries:amd64 (2019.20190605.51237-3build2), latexmk:amd64 (1:4.67-0.1), texlive-latex-recommended:amd64 (2019.20200218-1)
End-Date: 2021-01-16  21:02:19
```

It doesn't seem to have a huge list of packages removed so can I "calm down"?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't `apt-get purge` the configuration files still exist, if you were to reinstall a package should restore the package to its previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can calm down.

- This is a good example of a great time to use apt-get's `--simulate` flag. Test your removal before executing for real.
- It's also a reminder that apt-get shows you a list of all proposed changes for your approval. Read the list carefully before hitting 'Y'.

Comment: Yes, searching around for similar problems that flag seems to be a good practice. Especially when playing with new toys like regex and apt-get. Thanks.